# Running a node/express app forever on godaddy shared hosting

Tags: node.js, hosting, cpanel, shared-hosting

I have a deluxe hosting with cpanel account on gdaddy on which I'd like to host a nodejs/express app. I installed node manually with the help of this excellent guide https://ferugi.com/blog/nodejs-on-godaddy-shared-cpanel/ and I can start the node process manually (and background it) from the SSH session and the site runs: great!

Now I'm wondering what happens when the godaddy machine restarts. I guess the node process won't be restarted automatically and hence the app won't work.

Is there a way to restart the node process automatically should the machine restart? Note that since it's a shared hosting account there is no sudo access (afaik).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a simple bash script let's call it start-node-app.sh with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/cpaneluser/path-of-the-node-app
node app.js
```

Save the file, make it executable (chmod +x start-node-app.sh)

Then add a cron entry like this (you can do it via ssh using crontab -e or using the cPanel web interface)

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /home/cpaneluser/start-node-app.sh 2>&1 >> /home/cpaneluser/start-node-app.log
```

You should replace **cpaneluser** with your actual cPanel user, adjust the **paths** to suit your needs, but you got the point.

It should work on CentOS 6.x and 7.x (and since it's a cPanel/WHM server, it's pretty obvious that it runs CentOS)